# How do round off the elements of scipy.sparse.csr matrix to 2 decimal places ?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

It can't be converted to numpy array due to memory error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can apply `np.round` to the `data` attribute of the matrix:

```
In [34]: from scipy import sparse
In [35]: M = sparse.random(5,5,.2,'csr')
In [36]: M
Out[36]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [37]: M.A
Out[37]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.28058287, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.81478819, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.06805299, 0.51048128],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.64388578, 0.        ]])
In [38]: M.data
Out[38]: array([0.28058287, 0.81478819, 0.06805299, 0.51048128, 0.64388578])

In [39]: M.data=np.round(M.data,2)
In [40]: M.data
Out[40]: array([0.28, 0.81, 0.07, 0.51, 0.64])
In [41]: M.A
Out[41]: 
array([[0.  , 0.  , 0.28, 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.81, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.07, 0.51],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.64, 0.  ]])
```